# Is it possible to cluster markers based on city name in Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

for example, I have a list every city has latLong and city name.
Can I cluster markers based on city name?

edit 1: 
how to implement my algorithm using setAlgorithm() in ClusterManager?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: @JarinRocks how ?

Comment: You can write your own Algorithm and set it to ClusterManager  via `setAlgorithm()`

Comment: Could you provide me with a sample?

Comment: I don`t have sample, as I understand it not so easy

Comment: @VadimEksler yes I got it. Thank you :)

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/GridBasedAlgorithm.java